# OpenCV RTSP H264 capture

Tags: opencv, video, h.264, rtsp

I am using OpenCV 2.4.5 on windows 7 to capture RTSP stream.But I am getting some corrupt images in between.I found that the error is in decoding in ffmpeg layer.I want to drop these corrupt frames.But I am not able to do that because opencv Mat::empty never returns true.
What could be the root cause of this and please let me know the solution for the same.

Here is an image for the reference:

[image]

Comment: few suggestions for your question... [1] you say you `found that` the error is in the ffmpeg decoding layer... have you found out where the error is in ffmpeg or is this something you suspect... [2] also, you say you are unable to drop bad frames as Mat::empty never returns true, is that the expected behavior; as the frame, although it is corrupt, is certainly not empty

Comment: since the last time you posted, have you managed to solve the problem...

Comment: Any fixes to this problem? I have the same corruption with opencv/ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

One fix to be this problem could be to force the RTSP protocol to use TCP as a transport.
you can append `?tcp` into your URL e.g. `rtsp://ip-address:port/xyz?tcp` then pass it to open method.

This solution worked for me and I have tried with Axis, D-Link, Acti and Panasonic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 2.4.6 and no such frames. Nevertheless, ffmpeg is known to have issues with parsing h264 frames. Look for ffmpeg h264 parser patch or similar. Building ffmpeg with the patch and using it in your project should solve it.